# MySQL UPDATE IF SELECT Query

Tags: mysql

I need to build a mysql query that does the following:

- SELECT the count of rows for a user from posts table
- UPDATE the column fields of a row with ID = 15 only if the count result is less than or equal to 5

Here is what I have tried:

```
UPDATE posts SET post_title = 'my title' IF(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM posts WHERE (post_status = 'saved' AND user_id = 1) <= 5) WHERE ID = 15
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to perform these types of operations within a single query?

Comment: @spencer7593 The update needs to be done to one row only which has an ID of 15. I have updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There are several ways to incorporate a subquery into an UPDATE statement.

One way is to use a multi-table update, and use an inline view to return the count:

```
 UPDATE posts p
   JOIN (SELECT COUNT(c.id) AS cnt
           FROM posts c
          WHERE c.post_status = 'saved'
            AND c.user_id = 1
        ) v
     ON v.cnt <= 5
    SET p.post_title = 'my title'
  WHERE p.id = 15
  LIMIT 1
```

The inline view query (aliased as `v`) is run first. This will return one row (because of the COUNT aggregate). We then use a join operation to match to rows in the posts table (aliased as `p`).

For the join predicate, we reference the returned "count" from the inline view. If that's greater than five, then it won't match any rows from the posts table, so no rows will be updated.

There are several ways to obtain the same result:

```
UPDATE ( SELECT COUNT(c.id) AS cnt
           FROM posts c
          WHERE c.post_status = 'saved'
            AND c.user_id = 1
         HAVING COUNT(c.id) <= 5
       ) v
  JOIN posts p
    ON p.id = 15
   SET p.post_title = 'my title'
 LIMIT 1
```

Or

```
UPDATE posts p 
   SET p.post_title = 'my title'
 WHERE p.id = 15 
   AND ( SELECT COUNT(c.id) AS cnt
           FROM posts c
          WHERE c.post_status = 'saved'
            AND c.user_id = 1
       ) <= 5
 LIMIT 1
```